# Generating a random Character from range of 2 characters

Tags: rust

I would like to randomly give "flag" the value of either "D" or "C", but I'm having some problems...

Would appreciate if someone could help out on what I'm missing or provide an easy way to achieve this.

Tried this but without success:

```
let mut letter: char = rng.gen_range(b'A', b'Z') as char;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use an array of all of your options (in this case `['C', 'D']`) and use [`SliceRandom::choose`](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/seq/trait.SliceRandom.html#tymethod.choose) to pick one at random. I would generally recommend this since it doesn't assume that `'C'` and `'D'` are consequtive letters, which may not continue to be true if you were to extend your code to more than 2 characters in the future.

```rust
use rand::prelude::*;

let mut rng = thread_rng();
let letter = ['C', 'D'].choose(&mut rng);
```

[In Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ebbc9f50fe9085280c6092272d7bc92f)

---

Alternatively, if you really *do* want to use `gen_range` despite the above, you need to pass in a range value, like `'C'..='D'` (inclusive range from `'C'` to `'D'`). There's no need to use byte literals here, since `char` ranges are already valid.

```rust
use rand::prelude::*;

let mut rng = thread_rng();
let letter = rng.gen_range('C'..='D');
```

[In Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=050bda2c6f5502eee86fc24a95f5e870)

Comment: Tnx a lot, I tried your example and it works great. But do you know why I get: 
"method not found" on .choose in this context?  (line 27)
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=817e5e8595ffe5363a8ff87d62604092

Comment: @CultofTranquility Yes, you need to include the `use rand::prelude::*;` line from the examples (or import the `SliceRandom` trait directly). The error message in your playground code does describe this.